# Wordpress site: easy way to migrate server/url

Tags: wordpress

What is easiest way to change wordpress site. I have develop a site in wordpress for client and who do not have enough knowledge of doing changes in files.

Is there any way that she just upload the files and run some script for changing the path in files and site can be functional.

Answer (score 1):

You can add site relocation parameters to wp-config.php, re [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), but for other important details of changing domains or moving from localhost to a live domain and changing URLs in the database, use [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP | interconnect/it](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to deploy a WordPress site, what I always do is this:

1. dump the database to a .sql file.
2. Do a search and replace on the database for the development URL (devsite.local) and replace it with the new URL (thewebsite.com) *(no trailing slashes!!)*
3. Upload the site including the uploads folder
4. Replace the database with your .sql file

This is the only way I know to do a complete migration from a local server to the real server.

You can also do an export of the content though XML, but that doesn't work with images and some settings.

Comment: I am following the mention way but what shd be for client. I am thinking for client point of way.

Comment: Finding/replacing in the text dump with an eidtor will break serialized data.

Comment: I have done that with a lot of sites, and if do it like I mentioned above (without the trailing slashes) it will work!

Comment: I try to use a build server as much as posible, so when I checkin a new update to the source code repository it gets automatically build to the live server.